# matching on AST in Racket

Tags: racket

I'd like to write a function that matches on different syntax of the input argument, e.g.,

```
(define (foo e) 
  (match e
    [int (print "int")]
    [(and _ _) (printf "and")])
)
```

such that I can call it with:

```
(foo 1) --> prints "int"
(foo (and #t #f)) --> prints "and"
```

but that doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a short yet complete response to this.

The first thing is, you cannot do this with a procedure. There are predicates you can use to determine if something is a number, like `number?`, but you can't catch syntax like `and` with this.

But the really, really, really important point is that you can't catch anything like this: by the time `foo` sees `e`, the expander has already expanded any syntax and evaluated the expression. That is, for instance, `(and #t (+ 3 4))` has been converted into an expression like `(if #t (+ 3 4) #f)` and this expression is already evaluated by the time you see `e` inside the procedure, in which case `e` is just `7`. In Racket, arguments to procedures are evaluated before the procedure is called. This means, roughly, all syntax transformers are applied, and the resulting expanded expression is evaluated, *and then* the procedure is called on the resulting value.

If you only care about tinkering with s-expressions, you can `quote` the argument and play with the resulting list. `(quote (and 2 3)` will give you a list containing the symbol `'and` and not the syntax, so this probably isn't what you want. I mention it for some completeness.

The way to manage your question in Racket is to use macros. Again, the problem is that expressions passed as arguments to a procedure are *already evaluated* by the time the procedure is called, so you have to work at the level of `define-syntax` in order to catch expressions before they're expanded and evaluated. That is, to solve your specific problem you need something like a procedure which takes some syntax as an argument and gives back syntax:

```
#lang racket/base
(require (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (foo stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:literals (and)
    [(_ i:number)
     (syntax (displayln "int"))]
    [(_ (and a b))
     (syntax (displayln "and"))]))
```

This procedure takes some syntax and produces some other syntax. The syntax argument `stx` (which could be named anything, it's just convention) must match a clause or else it is a syntax error. When you define syntax, you are essentially making a new programming language and this is a new construct in that language. If it matches, such as the case `(and #t #f)`, it will replace the syntax `#'(foo (and #t #f))` with something like `#'(displayln "and")`. It won't actually display "and" until this is evaluated.

To get started on macros see [the Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html) or [the Racket Reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Macros.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the match pattern `int` matches everything.

```
> (match 42
      [int  "foo"]
      [_    "bar"])
"foo"
```

If you want to match the symbol `int` you need to write `'int`

```
> (match 'int
      ['int  "foo"]
      [_     "bar"])
"foo"
> (match 42
      ['int  "foo"]
      [_     "bar"])
"bar"
```

Also note that in you example: `(foo (and #t #f))` the arguments of the functions call are evaluated before the function is called. That is, first `(and #t #f)` is evaluated with `#f` as result. Then `foo` is callled: `(foo #f)`.

If you want to call `foo` with a list-and-symbols representation the expression, then use: `(foo '(and #t #f))`.

Answer (score 0):

To add just a bit to the excellent answer from law-of-fives, the feature I think you're looking for were called "FEXPR"s in Lisp. A FEXPR was a procedure that received the *syntax* of the arguments, rather than their values.

Several people pointed out the problems with FEXPRs, though (cf Wand, "The Theory of Fexprs is Trivial"); specifically, they make compilers very very unhappy. Instead, we now have Racket's macro system, which manages to combine expressiveness with a clear boundary between compile-time and run-time execution.